# How to get the CRM 2011 form based security role report?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, security-roles

I am looking for a way to get CRM 2011 form based security role report instead of manually going to each form of an entity and find the security roles. There must have been some way to get it either using some 3rd party tool or SQL Server?

```
EntityId | FormId | FormType | SecurityRoleId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, written a script to get the security roles which are not provided by Dynamics CRM 2011 out of box.

The trick that i have applied in my solution is by parsing the FormXml to get the security role ids of each form because i couldn't find any table where CRM is maintaining this association of form and role ids.

Composed the full answer at this github location:
[Entity's Form Based Security Roles](https://github.com/furqansafdar/Dynamics-CRM/blob/master/Entity's%20Form%20Based%20Security%20Roles.sql)